# text on image center and responsive

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

[image]

I want to make the text like this using html and css. And able responsive web and view on IE8

```
enter code here

<a class="btnSubmit">
<img src="btnSubmit.png">
<span>Submit</span>
</a>
```

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: you can use gradient colors as its simple backgound.. http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As G.L.P's comment suggets you can use [CSS gradients](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp) to get the background working.

For the "Responsive web" button you could look into setting the width in a % value, this scales to relatively to the webpage.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14302973/3666810) a nice explanation as to what to use, and when to use it

Try something like this:

HTML:

```
 <button>Submit</button>
```

CSS:

```
button {
    width:30%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(grey, white); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(grey, white);/* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(grey, white);/* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */ 
    background: linear-gradient(grey, white); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3czvuuwk/) to see this code in action

Comment: if I want to use the these code:<a class="btnSubmit">
<img src="btnSubmit.png">
<span>Submit</span>
</a>

Comment: @luckyViva Do you want that `<span> Submit </span>` to be "on" the `<img src="btnSubmit.png">`?

Comment: Yes,  the text on the images